# C# which context is bind to a form while a form is loading?

Tags: c#

I'd like to know more about the lifecycle of winforms. I know that the `BindingContextChanged` event sets the `Visible` property of the form to true. But I was wondering, which context is bind to the form? What triggers the `BindingContextChanged` so the forms property `Visible` is set to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't aware of a tight correlation between `BindingContext` and `Visible`, but *generally* each form simply gets a new `BindingContext`. If you need to do something funky with separate binding-contexts between different controls, then you have that option by assigning your *own* `BindingContext` to some controls.

Looking in reflector, it looks like the `BindingContext` is set for the first time diring the `get` in `ContainerControl` - in fact, that is the *only* place in the BCL where it appears to be `new`ed:

```
public override BindingContext get_BindingContext()
{
    BindingContext bindingContext = base.BindingContext;
    if (bindingContext == null)
    {
        bindingContext = new BindingContext();
        this.BindingContext = bindingContext;
    }
    return bindingContext;
}
```

i.e. it is lazily instantiated when a `BindingContext` is first needed, and assigning to `this.BindingContext` causes the event (etc) to be invoked.

Not sure why you think this ties into `Visible` - care to explain?

Comment: I was gathering information about the lifecycle of a winform. While I was looking into that I found this site: http://www.csharp411.com/c-winforms-form-event-order/ Here they say that the `BindingContextChanged` event makes the form (control) visible. So I was curious what triggers this event?

Comment: @Martijn - I suspect that is a misunderstanding; I'm speculating, but it is probably *in the process of becoming visible* (i.e. the property has been changed, cogs are whirring but it isn't complete yet); rendering the control contents may require a binding-context, which *causes* the binding-context-changed event to fire. Inspecting `Visible` at this point would then return true, even though the event hasn't fired yet (the visibility change isn't yet complete).

Comment: @Martijn - of course, you could stick a break point in an event-handler for binding-context-changed, and look at the call stack to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. How can I look at the call stack if I set a breakpoint? I mean, can I see where the property is set to true?

Comment: @Martijn - `this.Visible = true;` is the last thing that `.Show()` does, hence anything that happens is a *consequence* of the process of setting `Visible` to `true` (not the cause).